# Reading a text file line by line and converting it into a list using only read()?

Tags: python, list

So I have a txt file that contains the following numbers:

> 10
> 5
> 6
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 1
> 9
> 34
> 22
> 5

There is only one number per row. I want to put all the numbers in a list and use only the `read()` function. `readline()` or `readlines()` is not allowed.

This is what I've tried doing (note that I have to use a function like this):

```
def get_list1(text):
    result=[]
    for row in text:
        result.append(row)
    return result

with open("file.txt") as f:
    n = f.read()

l=get_list1(n)
print(l)
```

This is the output:

```
['1', '0', '\n', '5', '\n', '6', '\n', '2', '\n', '3', '\n', '4', '\n', '1',
 '\n', '9', '\n', '3', '4', '\n', '2', '2', '\n', '5']
```

As you can see it includes the `\n` and splits the numbers into its digits.

I want an output of

```
['10','5','6','2','3','4','1','9','34','22','5']
```

Comment: `l = f.read().split("\n")` ? or  `l = [n.strip() for n in f.read().split()]` or `l = list(map(int, (w.strip() for w in f.read().split())))`

Comment: Why you don't want to use `readlines`? You can split your string with `.splitlines()` but I don't know if it is OK with your restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

```
def get_list1(text):
    result=[]
    for row in text:
        result.append(row)
    return result

with open("test.txt") as f:
    n = f.read().split("\n")

l=get_list1(n)
print(l)
```

Or just use [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

```
def get_list1(text):
    result=[]
    for row in text:
        result.append(row)
    return result

with open("test.txt") as f:
    n = f.read().splitlines()

l=get_list1(n)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short way to do this is

```
def get_list1(text):
    return text.split("\n")

with open("file.txt") as f:
    get_list1(f.read())
```

or you can replace the function by something like

```
# takes care of empty lines as well and create actual integers in a list
l = list(map(int, (w.strip() for w in f.read().split() if w.strip())))
```

Yours is wrong because:

> ```
> def get_list1(text):
>     # text is a big text with \n in it
>     result=[]
>     # iterates the big blob of text as single characters
>     for row in text:
>         result.append(row)
>     return result
> ```

---

If you can not use any `split()` you can parse your file once character at time:

```
def get_list1(text): 
    """This function takes a text with included newlines \n, and processes it
    characterwise. Each character is added into a list of lists where the last 
    of it is always a list. A character is added to that last inner list 
    if it is not a \n. 
    If a \n is encountered, the last inner list is converted to a string
    (if not empty - to account for newlines in the input) and a new empty
    list is added for the characters of the next line. At the end the case
    of last character == \n is handled. A list of line texts is returned."""
    result=[[]]
    for character in text:
        if character == "\n":
            t = ''.join(result[-1]).strip()
            if len(t) > 0:
                # change list of characters into string
                result[-1] = int(t)
                result.append([])
            else:
                result[-1].clear()
            continue
        result[-1].append(character)

    try:
        t = ''.join(result[-1]).strip()
        if len(t) > 0:
            # change list of characters into string
            result[-1] = int(t)
        else:
            result = result[:-1] 
    except:
        result = result[:-1] 

    return result


print(get_list1("1\n11\n111\n111\n11111\n11\n"))
```

Output:

```
[1, 11, 111, 111, 11111, 11]
```